# How can I take the Multiple Gallery images into the Edit Text field Randomly

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-image, android-gallery

In my project I am try to pick the Gallery images and Emoticons into the Edit Text, I want like chat application. I need to pick the multiple Gallery images and add into the Edit Text field here with I attach my example image[image: This images contain text,Emoticons and gallery images]

Comment: Now You can see my images if you have any idea help me.

Answer (score 0):

You cant type messages with images inside the edittext for that fact that it wont scroll up or scroll left when editText is full.

**solution:**

what you need to do is create a string equivalent of the image

**example:**

`:)` = for happy face

`:(` = sad face 
etc.

```
rr:)tttt:(
```

After you hit enter you can then parse your string and check for the emoticons in string form and delete it then replace it with picture.

Comment: I send just example images but i want to pick images from the gallery also where ever we can attach the emoticons and images. I have almost done with pick images from Gallery using image getter method but i  can show one image at a time

Comment: Yes i can post but im having small issue in this line    d.setBounds(10,200, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());